# getting page not found on submit in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5

i have laravel project where on submit the form m getting error page not found whereas i have created route and all

routes :

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');

Route::post('/remove/{product}', 'ProductController@removeProduct')->name('remove');

Route::group(['as' => 'cart.', 'prefix' => 'cart'], function () {

    Route::post('/update/{product}', 'ProductController@updateProduct')->name('update');
});
Route::get('cart', 'ProductController@cart')->name('all');
Route::get('/{type}', 'IndexController@loadview');
```

view file :

```
<form action="{{route('remove', $slug)}}" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
                            @csrf

                            <input type="submit" name="remove" value="x Remove" class="btn btn-danger"/>
                            </form>
```

ProductController :

```
   public function removeProduct(Product $product){
    return 'something';
      $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
      $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
      $cart->removeProduct($product);
      Session::put('cart', $cart);
      return back()->with('message', "Product $product->title has been successfully removed From the Cart");
   }
```

Comment: try this return redirect()->back()->with('message', "Product $product->title has been successfully removed From the Cart");

Comment: removeProduct()  function is not even being called so how i supposed to redirect it somewhere

Comment: well i got this my self , Its argument that i have passed in controller is wrong

Comment: post it as answer so that anyone stuck with same problem got that or should i post it as asnwer ?

Comment: you post it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `Product` from `removeProduct(Product $product)` 
as in your route just made it variable

```
Route::post('/remove/{product}', 'ProductController@removeProduct')->name('remove');
```

but if you want to use this `removeProduct(Product $product)` kind of thing then

use resource routing for more details regrading same click [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)